# How can I create UIKeyboard with done button on top right corner?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uikeyboard

I need to show `UIKeyboard` with done button on top right corner ..please look into attached image..any help would be appreciated.

[image: **Something like this**]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help you. please check it out [BSKeyboardControls](https://github.com/SimonBS/BSKeyboardControls)

Answer (score 1):

Create a UIToolbar keep two bar buttons in that. Initially Hide that toolbar.

Show the toolbar on the textfield didBeginEditing delegate of textfield

and hide the toolbar in didEndEditing delegate of textfield

EDIT: As prashant said BSKeyboard offers what i said. See the look and feel of it here http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/bskeyboardcontrols

Comment: Ya..but in my case i want cancel button to animate along with keyboard up and down.
where as your solution ends up just showing ad hiding cancel button or Tool bar.

Comment: There are two solutions 1. Add animation to the Toolbar to move it from bottom. 2. Add the toolbar to the inputAccesoryView for the corresponding textfield. http://blog.carbonfive.com/2012/03/12/customizing-the-ios-keyboard/

Comment: Thank you @iPrabu,i'd rather prefer setting up inputAccesorryView.

Answer (score 0):

You should set inputAccessoryView propery of UITextField or UITextView to your custom view with all required buttons

> @property(readwrite, retain) UIView *inputAccessoryView
>
> Description
> The custom accessory view to display when the text field becomes the
> first responder The default value of this property is nil. Assigning a
> view to this property causes that view to be displayed above the
> standard system keyboard (or above the custom input view if one is
> provided) when the text field becomes the first responder. For
> example, you could use this property to attach a custom toolbar to the
> keyboard.